# ACM MIPT - One rectangle - sample input 2 incorrect?

Tags: algorithm

I am not clear about problem 15 (One rectangle) of ACM MIPT (http://acm.mipt.ru/judge/problems.pl?problem=015), specifically sample test case 2. Shouldn't the maximum rectangle for that case have area 2500 (rectangle being the one with vertices at (25, 25), (0, 50), (50, 100), (75, 75))? Here is the problem statement:

---

In the square 0 ≤ x ≤ 100, 0 ≤ y ≤ 100 there are N points with integer coordinates.
You should find out rectangle which has no any of given point (*meaning none of the given points??*) inside and has maximum possible area.

Remark: Points are permitted to be on the border of the rectangle.

Input: First line has the number N, 1 ≤ N ≤ 100, next N lines has coordinates of N points.

Output: Your program should output one number — maximum area.

Input#1
1
50 50

Output#1
5000

Input#2
3
25 25
50 50
75 75

Output#2
3750

---

Comment: Check out my answer. Hope that helps ! If it does, remember to upvote and accept ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the answer given is correct.

3750 comes as area if you consider the rectangle with the following endpoints:

(0, 50), (75, 50), (75, 100), (0,100).

Note: it touches points: (50, 50) and (75, 75) BUT does not have any of the three points inside it.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks! That definitely clarifies.